# Select item from unordered list in html

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items vertically. I want to select item from the list. Also, selected item will get green or any color. At a time, only one item can be selected from list. I can create the list. But, no idea how to make it selective and change color after selection by clicking mouse. Do I need to use any CSS for that?

```html
<div class="items">
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Give each `li` element a `tabindex`, and add this CSS:

```css
li:focus {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <ul>
    <li tabindex="1">Item1</li>
    <li tabindex="1">Item2</li>
    <li tabindex="1">Item3</li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

---

To do this in plain JavaScript:

1. Add a click event listener to the `ul` element.
2. If the event's target is an `li` element:
   2a. If there's an existing `li` that's selected, remove its class.
   2b. Add a selected class to the event's target.

```js
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', function(e) {   // 1.
  var selected;
  
  if(e.target.tagName === 'LI') {                                      // 2.
    selected= document.querySelector('li.selected');                   // 2a.
    if(selected) selected.className= '';                               // "
    e.target.className= 'selected';                                    // 2b.
  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

Note that **LI** must be capitalized in `e.target.tagName === 'LI'`.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML

```
<div class="items">
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

And the Jquery

```
$(".items ul li").click(function(){
    $(".items ul li").css("color","inherit");
    $(this).css("color","green");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74g21org/1/

Comment: Can we do it without using jQuery?

Comment: if you want to change your color when clicking an element you need jquery or javascript

Comment: I prefer simple Javascript. Can you please update the answer?

Comment: As @Elliott Says, its easier with jquery, javascript need more code to do it like you want

Comment: I am a beginner now. I am learning JS. So, I want to avoid library for learning purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery as such:

```js
$("ul li").on("click", function () {
    $("ul li").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).attr('class', 'selected');

});
```

```css
.selected {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tha for your answer. Can we do it in other way, without using jQuery?

Comment: @cyberoy Yes. you can do it with plain JavaScript.

Comment: @cyberoy Yes. Just give me a min.

Comment: No problem. Please take your time.

Comment: Actually, I need to hold the selected item and store it in a variable then need to send it back to server. Simple Javascript is good choice for it I think.

Comment: @cyberoy `jQuery` would be much easier to do this. It would be lesser lines of code as well as more maintainable in the future.

Comment: I know. But I want to avoid library. I am learning now, very beginner. I want to use Javascript for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with plain html and css like this:

```
.items li:active {
    color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8jwnfgp/1/

Comment: Thanks. But I actually need to select and hold the item. As, I need to send back the selected item to server.

Comment: In this case you really need javascript because you need to store selected item in a variable and send it either via form submission or AJAX request

Comment: Yes, I prefer Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

To expand on Bak's response, you will need to use Javascript to apply the styles such as color.

jQuery is probably the easiest way to go about doing as he suggested. This is a good place to start: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Also, don't forget to close your list item tags:

```
<li>Item1< / li>
```